# Существительное «показатель» употребляется с «больше» или «выше»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

*Вывел на рынок новую модель кедов Nike серии Air Max и добился продаж в объеме 9,7 млн руб., что на 27% больше/выше показателя прежнего маркетолога.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Нацкопрусе встречаются оба вражения, "показатель выше" и "показатель больше", но первый вариант встречается чаще.

> Из двух вариантов первого пятилетнего плана ― отправного, составленного в расчете на неблагоприятное стечение обстоятельств, и оптимального с учетом наилучших факторов, к реализации приняли оптимальный, **показатели которого были выше на 20%**. [Л. А. Муравьева. Социалистическая индустриализация: особенности, источники, методы (2003) // «Финансы и кредит», 2003.04.21]
>
> Этот **показатель выше апрельского на 10%**, когда подобный объем продаж оценивался в 674 млн. долл. [А. А. Чернов. Становление глобального информационного общества (2003)]

Меня немного смущает "показатель прежнего маркетолога". Я бы предпочел "показатель, достигнутый (полученный) прежним маркетологом".

Строго говоря, показатели человека это его вес, рост, пульс и т. п.

> ...медицинская комиссия, рассматривающая результаты ЭКГ, быстро отпустила Кизима и Макарова, а потом долго о чем-то совещалась. И наконец объявила: мои показатели неудовлетворительные...

Впрочем, если маркетолога оценивают по объему продаж... Но ведь цифра это меняется, нужно отнести ее к периоду времени: показатель прежнего маркетолога за последний год его работы, наилучший показатель прежнего маркетолога и т. п.

Дополнение.
Хотелось бы понять, как сравнивают успехи двух маркетологов, если они продвигали разные товары (модели) в разное время.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно говорят: **высокий показатель, чем выше показатель.**

Примеры:

**Чем выше показатель** КО (максимальное значение ― 2), тем больше выражено позитивное отношение.

Кроме того, у них **выше показатель** автономии.

У серебряного призера рейтинга ― французской Leroy Merlin **оказался выше показатель выручки** с одного квадратного метра ― 215 тыс. руб